# About detecting proxy setting using rome api

Tags: java, proxy, rss, rome

The  below provides an error when in lan behind a proxy ,but works properly outside lan/proxy.
Please let me know how I can rectify it

I used the code to detect proxy setting and it gave

[Detecting Windows/IE proxy setting using Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4933677/detecting-windows-ie-proxy-setting-using-java)

I am getting: proxy hostname : DIRECT No Proxy Does this mean I am not behind a Proxy Server?

I'm trying to use java rome-fetcher to acquire rss feeds for processing. Everything works fine when I have direct internet access.

However, I need to be able to run my application behind a proxy server.

The  below provides an error when in lan ,but works properly outside lan
Exception in thread "main" java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)

```
import java.util.Properties;
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.Writer;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

import com.sun.syndication.feed.synd.SyndEntry;
import com.sun.syndication.feed.synd.SyndFeed;
import com.sun.syndication.io.SyndFeedInput;
import com.sun.syndication.io.SyndFeedOutput;
import com.sun.syndication.io.XmlReader;


public class RomeLibraryExample {
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    URL url = new URL("http://rss.cnn.com/rss/cnn_topstories.rss");

   //System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", "DIRECT");
   // System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", "8080");


    HttpURLConnection httpcon = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection(Proxy.NO_PROXY);
    // Reading the feed



    SyndFeedInput input = new SyndFeedInput();
    SyndFeed feed = input.build(new XmlReader(httpcon));

    List<SyndEntry> entries = feed.getEntries();
    Iterator<SyndEntry> itEntries = entries.iterator();

    while (itEntries.hasNext()) {
        SyndEntry entry = itEntries.next();
        System.out.println("Title: " + entry.getTitle());
        System.out.println("Link: " + entry.getLink());
        System.out.println("Author: " + entry.getAuthor());
        System.out.println("Publish Date: " + entry.getPublishedDate());
        System.out.println("Description: " + entry.getDescription().getValue());
        System.out.println();
    }


}
```

}

Comment: What are your proxy server settings?  Is it "auto detect" or fixed? If it is auto detect the code in the link you gave will say direct even if the auto detection script assigns you a proxy.