# The import com.btr cannot be resolved

Tags: java, eclipse, import

```
import com.btr.proxy.search.ProxySearch;
```

Eclipse says that this import "com.btr cannot be resolved"
The complete code is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24696438/2404456).

How do I tell eclipse where to find it?

Answer (score 1):

I think `com.btr.proxy.search.ProxySearch` class not present in your class path.

If you are not using maven then you have to download `proxy-vole_20131209_bin.zip` file and configure it in your class path it has `ProxySearch` class. [Download from here](https://code.google.com/p/proxy-vole/downloads/list)

Comment: I don't see anything to indicate that maven is involved in the original question

Comment: @Derek I thought he was using maven and `ProxySearch` not present in his classpath.

Comment: Awesome! It solved the problem. This contained the jar I needed. But how do you find this out?

Comment: `import ** cannot be resolved"` i.e. class not present in your class path. So at that time we need to find the jar and configure it in class path.

Comment: I actually want to know how to find the correct jar. Sure, this zip file contains what I need, but I would never figure out its name... So how do you find it?

Comment: you have to find unwanted jars on basis of your eclipse error message, there is no other way

Answer (score 1):

com.btr belongs to a separate library. You can add it to your workspace by right clicking your current project, going to Build Path > Configure Build Path. Navigate to the Java Build Path among the icons on the left and selecting Libraries among the tabs given. Select add external jars and select the location of your jar file which should hold the library you're looking for.